# Cordova - Sleep mode break backbutton override

Tags: android, cordova, back-button

I use Cordova and get an iddue, at least on android (tested on 2 and 4)

I made an override of thebackButton behavior using addListener

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backbuttonListener, false);

function backbuttonListener(){
    if(Windows.currentWindow != null){
        Windows.currentWindow.hide();
    }
    else if(Container.currentPrint.page == 'main'){
        if(isMob) navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else{
        Container.setContent(Main_page);
    }
}
```

It work great, however, after a long period in sleep mode (app not closed), when user wake up his phone, the listnener don't work anymore, and the back button does nothing when pressed. It's annoying.

did someone get an explanation?

EDIT : Something goes wrong also with setTimeout after sleeping. the function is not called anymore
I'm the only one this occur?
EDIT 2
Maybe it's related, i get a redondant task with setTimeout :

```
function initialize_cron(){
if(isMob){
    if(navigator.connection.type != 'none'){
        somefunc()
    }
}
setTimeout(function(){
    initialize_cron()
},300000);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i get it.

In fact, there is a bug with setTimeout/intervall with large delays. i try to remove my 'cron' and all worked fine even after very long sleep, backbutton event and settimeouts.
So i made this to replace :

```
var initialize_cron = function(){
if(cron == 0){
    if(isMob){
        if(navigator.connection.type != 'none'){
            somefunc
        }
    }
}
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (cron == 30)
            cron = 0
        else
            cron++
        initialize_cron()
    // },300000);
    },10000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All I can recommend is that you reproduce the error and breakpoint it in Chrome DevTools via `chrome://inspect`. Have a look at the stack and see why the event isn't being fired. I attempted to reproduce it and couldn't get the same issue.

Also maybe it's worth checking if the listener is still present on `document` when the application is waked.

Comment: However, as far as i know, the backbutton listener does not exist on desktop, and there is no sleep mode. Maybe a good emulator could help me to track the problem, but not if the problem is a mobile device issue...

Comment: 'backbutton' is a custom event emitted by Cordova so in order to debug it you'll need to try and breakpoint where the event should be triggering on the device.

Comment: I still not found how to breakpoint it, because in standby mode, all JS process sleeps. So before standby, my function is called, after (a very long) standby, function is not called anymore... So neverone get this issue ?_?